# jQuery rotating Div around a point

Tags: jquery, rotation

I have had a look around SO but couldn't find any that were similar with answers.

I'm trying to get some div elements to rotate around a centre point. I have got them to change the degree position, however they don't slide around they just jump and also the divs themselves change their direction.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
//arrange blocks in a circle
var block = $("#rotator div").get(),
increase = Math.PI * 2 / block.length,
x = 0, y = 0, angle = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
    var elem = block[i];
    x = 140 * Math.cos(angle) + 150;
    y = 140 * Math.sin(angle) + 150;
    elem.style.position = 'absolute';
    elem.style.left = x + 'px';
    elem.style.top = y + 'px';
    var rot = 90 + (i * (360 / block.length));        
    angle += increase;
}
        $('.click').click(function() {

            var rotateDegree = $(this).data('rotate');


            $('#rotator').css({
                 '-moz-transform':'rotate(' + rotateDegree + 'deg)',
                 '-webkit-transform':'rotate(' + rotateDegree + 'deg)',
                 '-o-transform':'rotate(' + rotateDegree + 'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform':'rotate(' + rotateDegree + 'deg)',
                 'transform':'rotate(' + rotateDegree + 'deg)'
            });
        });
```

});

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3VtML/

if someone could help me solve this I would be very grateful.

Comment: can you please provide some graphical form of what should be state after 45 degrees of rotation and the state after 90 degrees, so that one can get a clear idea of what you want to do exactly

Comment: The div should stay upright. and then smoothly slide to the next div on the angle. So the content is always the right way up.